# How do you determine subtype of an entity using Inheritance with Entity Framework 4?

Tags: entity-framework, inheritance, entity-framework-4

I am just starting to use the Entity Framework 4 for the first time ever.  So far I am liking it but I am a bit confused on how to correctly do inheritance.

I am doing a model-first approach, and I have my Person entity with two subtype entities, Employee and Client.  EF is correctly using the table per type approach, however I can't seem to figure out how to determine what type of a Person a specific object is.

For example, if I do something like

```
var people = from p in entities.Person select p;
return people.ToList<Person>();
```

In my list that I form from this, all I care about is the Id field so i don't want to actually query all the subtype tables (this is a webpage list with links, so all I need is the name and the Id, all in the Persons table).

However, I want to form different lists using this one query, one for each type of person (so one list for Clients and another for Employees).

The issue is if I have a Person entity, I can't see any way to determine if that entity is a Client or an Employee without querying the Client or Employee tables directly.  How can I easily determine the subtype of an entity without performing a bunch of additional database queries?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `.OfType<Client>()` in your query to get just the clients.  See [OfType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx).

e.g. `entities.Person.OfType<Client>()` ...

Use `is` to test if a Person object is a specific sub-class, e.g. `if (p is Employee) ...`

BTW why isn't it `entities.People`?  Did you not select the pluralization option?

Comment: Excellent, didn't know the "is" check would work in that instance!  Thanks!  As a side note, I didn't do pluralization because this was just a quick example I could whip up without having to describe what all my entities mean, and I didn't know that it would pluralize Person to People correctly :)