# The entity set or function import <SubType> is not defined in the entity container

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Say I have two tables:

```
Person  
    PersonId   PK  <-----+
    FirstName            |
    LastName             |
                     Foreign Key  
Employee                 |
    PersonId   PK  <-----+
    Wage
```

**If I set up Entity Framework to have Employee inherit from Person then how can I do a query for just Employees?**

When I try to do it, I get this error:

> The entity set or function import Employees is not defined in the entity container MyEntityContainer.

Or it just won't compile (if I try to select from Employees directly).

It appears that the subtype does not get an entity made for it.

Am I out of luck or is there a trick to allow me to select the sub type only.

Answer (score 0):

This question answers it: [How do you determine subtype of an entity using Inheritance with Entity Framework 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2814860/16241)

I just needed to use OfType:

```
Persons.OfType<Employee>()
```